# Adding TreeView to a TableCeell in javafx

Tags: treeview, javafx, tableview

I need to add a TreeView to each cell in a particular column of a table.I am able to add Strings but I am not able to add TreeView. How can I do this?
This is my NodeInfo class

```
public class NodeInfo{
private TreeView<String> nodeTree;
private TreeItem<String> root;
private final Image rootIcon=new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/nodes.gif"));
private final Image folderIcon=new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/folder.gif"));
public void settreeView(String s)
{
nodeTree = new TreeView<>();
    nodeTree.setEditable(true);
    root = new TreeItem<>("Rootnode", new ImageView(rootIcon));
    root.setExpanded(false);
    nodeTree.setRoot(root);
    for(int i=0;i<3; i++)
    {
    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(sharedFolders.get(i), new ImageView(folderIcon)));
    }
}
public TreeView<String> gettreeView()
{
 return nodeTree;
}
}
```

And this is controller class for UI

```
   public class GrapevineController implements Initializable {
   @FXML 
   private TableView<NodeInfo> tableView;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<NodeInfo, TreeView<String>> nodeTree;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<NodeInfo, String> name;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<NodeInfo, String> favourite;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<NodeInfo, String> updates;
   @FXML 
   public static ObservableList<NodeInfo> sourceTree = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   @Override
     public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle r){
      tableView.setEditable(true);
    nodeTree.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NodeInfo, TreeView<String>>   ("treeView"));
   name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NodeInfo, String>("MacAddress"));
   favourite.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NodeInfo, String>("favourites"));
   updates.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<NodeInfo, String>("update"));

    tableView.setItems(sourceTree);


   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but if you use a propertyValueFactory ("treeView"), you need a getTreeView().  Notice you didn't capitalize the T in tree.

Comment: Actually I needed this for my project. I am new to javafx and learning by myself, therefore I keep on facing such problems.

Comment: There is a problem. when I add this treeview to the table cell, the cell becomes too big. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: A TreeView usually is big so the TableCell will be big as well.  I think you should re-write the question or ask a new one and explain what you're trying to do.  I found it strange to put a TreeView in a table.  There's probably a better solution.

Comment: @brian I want to list all the computers in my network in the cells of a table and when I click on the expand button it gives me the shared folders on that computer. I am able to list all computers and their shared resources, now I want to add them to the GUI.

Comment: Then I would just use a tree like in [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm)  Or if using javafx - 8 [a TreeTable](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html).  But a simple tree will be just fine unless you want to list resource attributes like the file example in the tree table link.

Comment: @brian I have others attributes as well for each computer. Like host name mac address etc which should also appear in the same row as the ip of computer. like-
>172.16.144.145   Jai-pc    mac address
and as i told you expand button shows shared resources

Comment: Then I would still suggest a TreeView without a table.  You could bind the attributes to labels and show them separately.  BTW, I just tried that tree table example with `createNode(new File("//AMD/D"));' and it listed my networked D drive (named d on amd).

Comment: why do you think its not good to use treeview in tablecells whereas tableview provides a lots of good features which I can exploit with treeview and tableview combined together. Like having an object as the content of the table rows and each column correspond to a different attribute of the object.

Comment: That's exactly what a treetable does.  If you can't use javafx8 and you still want a table I would put the table in the tree view instead of the other way around.  If your whole tree takes up one cell, then you only get a one row table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48499/discussion-between-krishna-and-brian)